# Directory is getting created with special characters in shell scripts (mkdir)

Tags: bash, scripts

I am very new to shell script and ubuntu in shell script i am using following commands

```
sudo mkdir /home/microservice
cd /home/microservice
```

But when i ls the folders i see weird special characters

[image]

Please help me on this

Comment: You probably create the script on Windows. It adds end-of-line symbols. Use Notepad++ or other software that doesn't spoil texts..

Comment: I did created in windows but used notepad++ let me try some editor, thanks for help

Comment: Do you mean the green background of `scripts`? That is nothing weird. It means that the folder is writable for all users. If you're the only user, that is nothing to worry about.